# SQL query to get users who have only single specified role

Tags: sql, database, join, oracle11g

**goal**: I want to filter out users who have only a single specified role assigned.

**expected result**: should display user id with specified role id

**actual result**: I am getting user IDs who have more than a single specified role assigned.

**error messages**: NO error messages

**What I have done**:
I have two table

first one is *user_profile* and other one is *user_profile_role*. I am joining these 2 tables to filter out the users who have role id  as 10005. some users contains more than single role ids. some users only contain role id  10005.

I want to only list down the users who have role id as 10005. but they shouldnt contains non other roles ids.

below is my user_profile table

---

| id | enabled |
| --- | --- |
| 2222 | 1 |
| 3333 | 1 |
| 4444 | 1 |
| 5555 | 1 |

---

below is my user_profile_role table

| id | role_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2222 | 10005 |
| 2222 | 10004 |
| 3333 | 10005 |
| 4444 | 10005 |
| 5555 | 10004 |
| 5555 | 10005 |

---

Im using below SQL query to filter out above I mentioned. But it seems my sql query not outputing desired result.

```
select distinct  u.id,u.enabled,ur.role_id
from USER_PROFILE u right outer join USER_PROFILE_ROLE ur
    on u.id=ur.id
where u.enabled=1 AND ur.role_id='10005';
```

when I run above query I am getting output as below ( which is not I want)

| id | enabled | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2222 | 1 | 10005 |
| 3333 | 1 | 10005 |
| 4444 | 1 | 10005 |
| 5555 | 1 | 10005 |

below is the output I want

| id | enabled | role_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3333 | 1 | 10005 |
| 4444 | 1 | 10005 |

If anyone can point out what I am missing in my sql query and point me a direction , I would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select id, enabled
from (
  select
    u.id,
    u.enabled,
    sum(case when r.role_id = 10005 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_searched,
    count(*) as cnt
  from user_profile u
  join user_profile_role r on r.id = u.id
  where u.enabled = 1
  group by u.id, e.enabled
) x
where cnt_searched = cnt
```

Comment: when I paste the above SQL query , I got an error " from user_profile u" line. it says that "missing expression"

Comment: @Nadee Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler one:

```
SELECT up.id, up.enabled, x.role_id 
FROM
   (SELECT id, role_id
    FROM user_profile_role
    GROUP by id 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT role_id)=1) AS x
LEFT JOIN user_profile up ON up.id=x.id
WHERE x.role_id='10005';
```

In this way, the subselect contains just the user_profile_role elements having a single role_id per id. Then you can join this subselect with the user_profile and filter for the elements having the needed role.

It is faster and more efficient since the internal optimizer can work better on this query.